# ORA 00907 Missing Right Parenthesis

Tags: oracle

I am getting this Error of "Missing Right Parenthesis" on the Query below. Can someone rectify the mistake please?

```
SELECT 
    DESCRIPTION,
    TOTAL_ADMISSION,
    EMERGENCY,
    NORMAL      
  FROM TABLE (ORDERENTRY.PKG_S04REP00031.ADMISSION_SUMMARY(P_START_DATE = to_date('31/08/2021', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
                                                         P_END_DATE = to_date('01/09/2021', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
                                                         P_ADMISSION_TYPE    = 'NORMAL'
                                                         /*P_ORDER_LOCATION_ID => :P_ORDER_LOCATION_ID, */
                                                         P_LOCATION_ID = 'K01'));
```

Comment: Your code is not well formatted, bu it is easy to see that there are missing commas between the params, and in pl/sql you use -=> (as in the commented part, no = to specify the value after the parameter name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
SELECT 
    DESCRIPTION,
    TOTAL_ADMISSION,
    EMERGENCY,
    NORMAL      
  FROM TABLE (ORDERENTRY.PKG_S04REP00031.ADMISSION_SUMMARY(P_START_DATE => to_date('31/08/2021', 'dd/mm/yyyy') , 
                                                           P_END_DATE   => to_date('01/09/2021', 'dd/mm/yyyy') , 
                                                           P_ADMISSION_TYPE => 'NORMAL' , 
                                                           --P_ORDER_LOCATION_ID => :P_ORDER_LOCATION_ID, 
                                                           P_LOCATION_ID => 'K01')
                                                           );
```

You are using `select from table(package.function`, therefore

- Parameters values in functions or packages follow the sign `=>` not `=`
- Parameters are separated by comma
- I replaced `/* */` just for `--`, just for cosmetic purposes, as both represent comments, but the later is more common when you want to comment just one line

Comment: Thank u Roberto! Now I want to add IN clause in P_LOCATION_ID which will select from a subquery and again getting missing Paranthesis error. I am trying it like.. P_LOCATION_ID in (select location_id from DEFINITIONS.LOCATIONS)

Comment: @xajid, please accept this answer and post another question with the new issue explained in detail.